# QR factorization and orthogonality

Tags: linear-transformations, orthogonality, least-squares

I have to answer these 2 questions:

[image]

I'm not sure where to begin...any ideas?

Comment: $O$ is the zero matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

since $Q^TQ=I$, we have:
$$
A^TA=\left(Q\begin{bmatrix}
R\\O\end{bmatrix} \right)^T
\left(Q\begin{bmatrix}
R\\O\end{bmatrix} \right)=[R^T,O]Q^TQ\begin{bmatrix}
R\\O\end{bmatrix}=R^TR
$$

Comment: So for part be is true because $R^T R$ = $LL^T$?  but is $R=L^T$ or $R=L$?

Comment: This prove the claim a). In general the claim b) is false.